# HP Pavillion G4 2000 touchpad is not working

Tags: touchpad, hp-pavilion

I have this Pavillion whose Touchpad stopped working a while ago, it didn't respond and the enabled/disabled LED doesn't turn on either. So then I bought another front case (because the touchpad is embedded in it) and replaced it for the "bad" one, but the touchpad doesn't work either. What are the chances of this being a motherboard issue? Is it more feasible that the "new" (second hand) touchpad I bought is broken too? What are other models which I can use to check if both touchpads are indeed working or not? I don't have any other "spare" G4 to test it.

**Edit:**
I also tried to use it on Linux just in case it was a driver issue but like Windows, it doesn't even list the hardware.

Comment: Update touch-pad driver . The file mentions methods used to enable / disable the TouchPad https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=56113256b09443f6&id=56113256B09443F6%21105

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried on Linux and, like Windows, it doesn't even list the hardware.